# Calculating work of an object moving up a slope

Tags: work

If an object is being pushed across a horizontal surface, the equation for the work done is $W = F s$, where $s$ is the horizontal displacement.

If an object is being lifted to a height of $h$, the equation for the work done is $W = F h$, where $h$ is the vertical displacement.

If an object is being pushed up a slope, or if a human is moving up a flight of stairs, however, only the vertical displacement is concerned in calculating work, while the horizontal displacement is omitted. Why is this so?

(With hindsight, I think this is a conceptual misunderstanding that only arises because it is quoted out of context!)

Comment: is the object being pushed by constant velocity, or constant force up the slope?

Comment: What is F? The answer lies in what you consider and not consider as acting forces F. If you spell that out, the answer becomes clear. In your example the force is friction on the one side and gravity the other.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on what forces exactly you are looking at. If it's friction & gravity, then total work done against them is :
$$ \begin{align}
W &= F_g h + F_{fr}~\ell \\ 
  &= F_g h + F_{fr}~ \frac {h}{\sin \theta} \\
  &= h \left( F_g  + F_{fr}~ {\sin \theta}^{-1} \right)
\end{align}
$$

Answer (score 0):

You have to consider the forces acting on that body.

If the body moving on a slope experiences no horizontal force i.e. its velocity in horizontal direction is zero, no work will be done in horizontal direction. But, if you consider a force acting in vertical direction then work will be done by the body to move in vertical direction.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the fact that (Work)W = F.S
                               (Work Done)W = FS Cos(theta)
We will not consider Horizontal motion because Weight of the object makes 90 Degrees with Horizontal displacement which gives Work Done in Horizontal Displacement as Zero [Cos(90) = 0] .

Comment: However, for $FS Cos(\theta)$, $\theta$ is not zero for a slope, so weight does do work.